# Navigating from Google Reader back to Gmail

Tags: gmail, google-reader

I often use the little links that Google apps display at the header of the page to switch between Gmail, Calendar, Reader, Documents, etc.

However, when I go to Google Reader, I can't easily get back to Gmail: It's not listed at all, unless I select `More/Even More` from the menu. Obviously I can just use a bookmark, but it seems very odd.

[image: Menu bar example]

Is there a way I can change or customize what links are shown in each Google app?

Comment: It's first choice in mine version. But what is this Custom there?

Comment: Does your browser support tabs? It's so much easier to leave them both open.

Comment: You also seem to have 'Web' there twice. Which browser are you using, and do you have any greasemonkey scripts or plugins which may be breaking the links?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Kudos to [Lipis](https://webapps.stackexchange.com/users/408/lipis) for a nudge in the right direction:

> It's first choice in mine version. But what is this Custom there?

Turns out the problem was the Firefox "[Custom Google search](https://addons.mozilla.org/en-US/firefox/addon/13996/)" extension, V1.1.2 -  Disabling this fixed the problem.

Answer (score 2):

Mine it does:
[image]

Answer (score 0):

I solved that particular problem by using the Faviconize and Perma Tab extensions for Firefox. Now I have small, permanent tabs in my browser for Gmail, Reader, Calendar, and Voice. No need to use the Google-provided links.